# Php - Count multidimensional complex array values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, count, iteration

Have to count **number** of questions (`questions_row_id`)

- evaluator wise and settings wise

From the following array:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "questions_row_id" => 1
      "settings_row_id" => 1
      "evaluator_row_id" => array:3 [▼
        0 => "1"
        1 => "4"
        2 => "101"
      ]
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "questions_row_id" => 2
      "settings_row_id" => 1
      "evaluator_row_id" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "1"
        1 => "100"
      ]
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "questions_row_id" => 4
      "settings_row_id" => 3
      "evaluator_row_id" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "1"
        1 => "101"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

What I am looking for:

For (Evaluator id == 1 and settings id == 1) number of questions = 2

and again
for (Evaluator id == 1 and settings id == 3) number of questions = 1

Need some hints on how to approach this and if possible any working samples are also appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe

```
  $evaluators = [];

  // start digging
  foreach ($myarray as $i1 => $set1) {

    // continue digging
    foreach ($set1 as $i2 => $set2) {

      // each evaluator (1, 4 and 101)
      foreach ($set2['evaluator_row_id'] as $evaluator_id) {

        // build new array with questions and settings elements
        $settings_id = $set2['settings_row_id'];
        $evaluators[$evaluator_id][$settings_id][] = $set2['questions_row_id'];
      }
    }
  }
```

Then to count the questions for each evaluator, by each setting ID...

```
  $question_counts = [];
  foreach ($evaluators as $evaluator_id => $settings_list) {
    foreach ($settings_list as $setting_id => $question_ids) {
      $question_counts[$evaluator_id][$setting_id] = count($question_ids);
    }
  }

  print_r($question_counts);
```

Output

```
Array(
  [1] => Array(
    [1] => 2
    [3] => 1
  )

  [4] => Array(
    [1] => 1
  )

  [101] => Array(
    [1] => 1
    [3] => 1
  )

  [100] => Array(
    [1] => 1
  )
)
```

Comment: Yeah it looks much more approachable now but i am still sorta stuck

Comment: OK, can you explain what you want to count exactly? I'll edit the answer to count the questions.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have seen the edited answer. It counts the number of questions per evaluator. I needed the number of questions (evaluator and settings) wise.

What I am looking for:

For (Evaluator id == 1 and settings id == 1) number of questions = 2
and again
for (Evaluator id == 1 and settings id == 3) number of questions = 1

Comment: I think I understand now, answer updated.